# Prepending text to html elements using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Javascript for formatting the time to a localized format using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` method.

I have several instances of time strings in 24h format i want to localize in a HTML page, for example:

```html
<span class="timeclass">18:45</span> //and so on..
```

And i am able to format the time with the following code, which uses a `Date` object:

```js
            let locale = 'en-US'; // this variable changes, example 'en-UK', etc
            let time = new Date('1971-12-12T18:45');
            console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { 
              hour: 'numeric',
              minute: 'numeric',
            }).format(time));  //output is "6:45 PM"
```

As the code shows, i added a dummy date in order for the `Date` object to be semantically correct. Now, i'm trying to write a function to replace all instances of times contained within `timeelem` classes:

```js
var locale = 'en-US';
var timeformat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { 
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
});

timeelements = document.querySelectorAll('.timeclass');
timeelements.forEach((element) => { 
timeelements.textContent= timeformat.format(timeelements.textContent);  
 });
```

But it is not working because it is getting the time in the format `18:45` instead of `1971-12-12T18:45`. What is the best way to prepend such dummy date to the string? The date is only relevant for the localization function to work, by the way.

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. In fact, avoid using `innerHTML` entirely because that's how you get XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose any date you want, as long as it is in the correct format. You can do something like this: [WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcxn9aty/)

> HTML

```
<span class="timeclass">18:45</span>
<span class="timeclass">18:15</span>
<span class="timeclass">11:45</span>
<span class="timeclass">02:45</span>
<span class="timeclass">22:45</span>
<span class="timeclass">23:45</span>
<span class="timeclass">18:00</span>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
timeelements = document.querySelectorAll('.timeclass');
timeelements.forEach((element) => {
  console.log("elem ", element.innerHTML);
  // Append any date. Use your birthday.
  const timeString12hr = new Date('1970-01-01T' + element.innerHTML + 'Z')
    .toLocaleTimeString({}, {
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      hour12: true,
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric'
    });
    
  element.innerHTML = timeString12hr
});
```

**------------------------UPDATED------------------------**

```
var locale = "en-US";

var timeformat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
});

timeelements = document.querySelectorAll('.timeclass');
timeelements.forEach((element) => {
  console.log("elem ", element.innerHTML);
    const timeString12hr = new Date('1970-01-01T' + element.innerHTML + 'Z');
  element.innerHTML = timeformat.format(timeString12hr)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i need to use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` instead of `toLocaleTimeString`, i cannot specify a timezone or 12 hour format. `en-US` is a variable and what i want is localization according to that variable (for example, `en-UK` returns 24h time format). I will edit my question in order to clarify that.

Comment: You should edit this answer to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Esquirish I have updated the javascript code for your dynamic requirment.